# How to make a Semantic Ui React Sidebar With Dropdown

Tags: reactjs, menu, semantic-ui, sidebar

Im trying to achieve `Semantic Ui React Sidebar With Dropdown

I want it like this:

[image]

I know its a lot to request but i hope you help me... Im trying to add a dropdown on my menu

This is my current sidebar code:

```
import React from 'react';
import cn from 'classnames';
import { Icon, Menu } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function Sidebar(props) {
  const classes = cn(
    'ui',
    'sidebar',
    'push',
    'left',
    'inverted',
    'menu',
    'vertical',
    'animating',
    { visible: props.toggleMenu }
  );

  return (
    <div className={classes}>
      <Menu.Item as={Link} to="/admin">
        Dashboard <Icon name="home" />
      </Menu.Item>
      <Menu.Item as={Link} to="/admin/orders">
        Orders
      </Menu.Item>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and it looks like this:

[image]

Btw here is where i get the sidebar code... https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/sidebar/

*Help a newbie out?* Thanks so much in advance!!!

Comment: please add a codesandbox

Comment: ok ill try thanks for fast reply

Comment: sadly i cant :(... i hope the code i provided is enough also i added a link on where i based my sidebar

Comment: it is basically a css fix but personally without a working example, i cant help you more.

Comment: ok i put my code on sandbox how to give it to you?

Comment: just share the link

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234395/discussion-between-xatifx-and-apostolos).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-andras-vm76y) which implements basic expand/collapse functionality but without icons.
You can adapt the logic to your code.

The main idea is to store the expanded/collapsed menus in your state

`const [expandState, setExpandState] = useState({});`

and depending on their state, to show hide sub menu items.

```
  <Menu.Item as={Link} to="/admin">
    <i className="fa fa-home" />
    Dashboard
    <span
      style={{ float: "right" }}
      onClick={() =>
        setExpandState({
          ...expandState,
          dashboard: !expandState.dashboard
        })
      }
    >
      Expand/Collapse
    </span>
    {expandState.dashboard ? (
      <Menu.Item as={Link} to="/admin/orders">
        Orders2
      </Menu.Item>
    ) : null}
  </Menu.Item>
```

Comment: @xAtifx that's why a codesandbox is always helpful in these cases :)

Comment: im new on stack overflow so sometimes i dont give much details

Comment: this ones out of question on my post but you know how to make smooth dropdown onclick? its fine if you dont answer

Comment: hmm i guess with a transition

Answer (score 0):

**Just float the icon left**

```
    <Icon name='home' style={{float : "left"}}/>
```

**OR**

you can use css

*** please check class Name ***

```
    i {
      float: left;
      margin-right: 12px !important;
    }
    the menu item itself just becomes an a element
    
    a {
      text-align: center;
      line-height: 40px;
    }
```

Comment: thanks the icon is fixed but the main question here is dropdown menu i dont have any dropdown menu

Comment: bro i really hate when people just downvote me when im just asking. a question you can just ask me properly to adjust my post :(

Comment: i didn't do it bro !

Comment: oh sorry thought you did anyways enjoy the upvote :)